# Mem issues with array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have the following C code:

```
    int rand_num=0;
    int card_vnum=0;
    int legendary[] = { 400, 401, 402, 407 }; //Legendary
    int epic[] = { 403, 404, 408, 409, 410, 416 }; //Epic
    int rare[] = { 405, 406, 414 }; //Rare
    int uncommon[] = { 411, 412, 413, 415, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424 }; //Uncommon
    int common[] = { 425, 426 }; //Common
    int arr_size=0;
    int picked_arr=0;

    rand_num = number_range(1,1000);

    if ( rand_num > 0 && rand_num <= 2 )
    {
        arr_size = sizeof(legendary)/sizeof(legendary[0]);
        picked_arr = number_range(0, arr_size);
        card_vnum = legendary[picked_arr];
debugmsg("Legendary card");
    }
    else if ( rand_num > 2 && rand_num <= 50 )
    {
        arr_size = sizeof(epic)/sizeof(epic[0]);
        picked_arr = number_range(0, arr_size);
        card_vnum = epic[picked_arr];
debugmsg("Epic card");
    }
    else if ( rand_num > 50 && rand_num <= 200 )
    {
        arr_size = sizeof(rare)/sizeof(rare[0]);
        picked_arr = number_range(0, arr_size);
        card_vnum = rare[picked_arr]; //memory issue here? vnum can end up as 403 (Epic)
debugmsg("Rare card");
    }
    else if ( rand_num > 200 && rand_num <= 450 )
    {
        arr_size = sizeof(uncommon)/sizeof(uncommon[0]);
        picked_arr = number_range(0, arr_size);
        card_vnum = uncommon[picked_arr];
debugmsg("Uncommon card");
    }
    else if ( rand_num > 450 && rand_num <= 1000 )
    {
        arr_size = sizeof(common)/sizeof(common[0]);
        picked_arr = number_range(0, arr_size);
        card_vnum = common[picked_arr]; //memory issue here? vnum can end up as 411 (Uncommon)
debugmsg("Common card");
    }

    debugmsg("Card: %d, chance: %d", card_vnum, rand_num);
```

Example results (should have been a Common card):

```
Debug: Common card
Debug: Card: 411, chance: 930
When you open your hand, you're holding... (Uncommon) card
```

number_range (from the Smaug MUD codebase):

```
int number_range( int from, int to )
{
    if ( (to-from) < 1 )
            return from;
    return ((number_mm() % (to-from+1)) + from);
}

int number_mm( void )
{
    int *piState;
    int iState1;
    int iState2;
    int iRand;

    piState             = &rgiState[2];
    iState1             = piState[-2];
    iState2             = piState[-1];
    iRand               = (piState[iState1] + piState[iState2])
                        & ((1 << 30) - 1);
    piState[iState1]    = iRand;
    if ( ++iState1 == 55 )
        iState1 = 0;
    if ( ++iState2 == 55 )
        iState2 = 0;
    piState[-2]         = iState1;
    piState[-1]         = iState2;
    return iRand >> 6;
}
```

I'm having issues where if the random number (that's what `number_range` does) falls into an ifcheck, it sometimes grabs from the wrong array. I assume this is a memory issue where I may be sizing the arrays wrong.

I have example issues in the comments above. The goal is once it falls into an ifcheck, it grabs a random number from the specific array.

The issue is sometimes it grabs a random number from the wrong array. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the code that you use in order to generate the random number? Why don't your try to print the **rand_num** value in order to understand which value does it assume?

Comment: The random number code works correctly, I verified that. I'll post a print of the rand_num in my OP.

Comment: The code that you've posted seems correct, but I still don't know how you generate the random number so could be difficult to understand where the problem is. I've also tested your code with a function that I've personally defined and everything works.

Comment: There's a good reason why you were asked to provide all the relevant code, we can't tell if the randomization function is inclusive or not (can it return the upper limit). If not, why do you check that `rand_num <= 1000`. If it does, you're accessing out of bounds (you should use `picked_arr = number_range(0, arr_size-1);`. Either way - we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: Why not just use rand() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
return ((number_mm() % (to-from+1)) + from);
```

can return the wrong index for an array.

Let's say `from = 0` and `to = 5`. Then, `to-from+1 = 6`. The range of values that can evaluate to is `[0-5]`. However, you want that range to be [0-4].

Changing that line to

```
return ((number_mm() % (to-from)) + from);
```

will fix that problem.

The other alternative is to change how the function gets called. Instead of using

```
    picked_arr = number_range(0, arr_size);
```

you can use

```
    picked_arr = number_range(0, arr_size-1);
```

Comment: Can this be fixed by doing a -1 in the card code? number_range is a core component to Smaug and I'm wary of changing such an important function. The goal if number_range is to pick a random number from `from` to `to` and if `[0-5]` comes out when you input 0 and 5, that is working as intended

Comment: @Zeno, that's the alternate strategy that I added to my answer.